# how to upgrade ruby version of my local custom gem "my_gem"

Tags: ruby, rubygems, version

I have created a custom gem named "my_gem" 
 with ruby version 2.2.0 but i want to upgrade it
 with ruby  version 2.5.1

Comment: Something stopping you?

Comment: My problem is,  I do not know to do this.

Comment: Then do not do it. I assumed when you wrote "i want to upgrade it " that you did. I guess this problem is solved then.

Comment: what if i remove version part from .....
spec.add_development_dependency "rake", "~> 10.0"
spec.add_development_dependency "rspec", "~> 3.0"
then bundle install or bundle update

Comment: You can change the **required** Ruby min/max version to restrict what versions of Ruby a gem can be installed with, but the gem itself's version is only restricted by the code you write. If you use features that weren't available in versions `1.8.7`, but were added in `1.9.1`, then it would be wise to set the minimum version. Other than that, you don't "upgrade" a gem because a new Ruby version came out, you only restrict it.

Answer (score -1):

Install the same gem when you're using Ruby 2.5.1.